# How to create a string with shell output (backticks) in Bash?

Tags: string, bash

I have been trying to create a string with a variable number of characters in it for a benchmark program. I am trying to use this to set up my messages string:

```
messages=`perl -e 'print "X" x $size'`
```

The goal is to create a dynamic number of characters. For example, if $size is 1 then there will be one X. If size is 5 then messages will be XXXXX. This doesn't seem to work and the output is blank.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I thought you knew everything Google.

Comment: Your problem is with the perl code, not the backticks.

Comment: I wish! I just realized the problem is with $size, but I can't seem to escape it so the script realizes it's a bash variable and not meant to be in the backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `$size` is not evaluated by bash is that you enclosed it in single quotation marks (`'`). This gets more obvious if you use the `$(...)` syntax instead of the backticks:

```
messages=$( perl -e 'print "X" x $size' )
```

The principle is that everything inside single quotes is not touched by bash (only the quotes are stripped finally after word splitting), while things in double quotes get the various shell expansions (without quotes even more).

Thus Perl here gets `$size` and can only try to evaluate this as a perl variable.

As already said by other Diego, swapping the quotation signs around can help:

```
messages=$( perl -e "print 'X' x $size" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
messages=`perl -e 'print "X" x shift' $size`
```

You need to evaluate `$size` in bash, not in perl. This way you pass it as a command-line argument to the script and in Perl you fetch with a single `shift`.

Comment: Nice solution to avoid shell quoting hell

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
messages=`perl -e "print \"X\" x $size"`
```

or even, playing with quotes:

```
messages=`perl -e "print 'X' x $size"`
```

Comment: Perl's quote operators are handy here (for more complex scripts anyway): `msg=$(perl -e "print q(X) x $size")`

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMHO calling `perl` and `awk` for simple string processing is [hackish](http://www.jargondb.org/glossary/hackish). A simple task like this can be done directly:

```
in='X' out='' x=5
for ((i = 0; i < x; ++i)); do out+="$in"; done
```